# passing stdio stream to another function c++

Tags: c++, stream, stdio

I have a function that opens and writes some stuff to a stdio FILE* stream. I then call another function that will build an xml that I want to then write to that same stream.  Rather than passing that string xml back to the original function, because it may get very big, can I pass that open stream to the xmlbuilder function and continue writing to the same stream, and where it left off, while in the xmlBuilder function?

Comment: One word answer: Yes.

Comment: Terrible mistmatch of tag (c++) and mechanism - C-style  `FILE*`

Comment: hmmm, that's odd, I had 'c-style' tag there along with 'stream' but only three of them showed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, something like this:

```
void writeOtherStuff(FILE* pFile)
{
    fputs("some more data\n", pFile);
}

void myFunction()
{
   FILE* pFile = fopen("myfile.txt", "w");
   if (!pFile)
       return;
   fputs("some data\n", pFile);
   writeOtherStuff(pFile);
   fclose(pFile);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Passing a `FILE *` pointer is no different from passing any other type of pointer.